# Issue running Joern

Tags: neo4j, gremlin-server, joern

Spent the last few days meticulously attempting to get Joern to function properly to no avail. I've even used the docker image provided by mckeimic/joern/ with no resolution.

- Ubuntu 16.04
- py2neo==2.0
- neo4j (attempted versions 2.1.5 and 2.1.8)
- OpenJDK 1.7
- gremlin-plugin downloaded and installed following the
  instructions (with mvn clean package -Dlicense.skip=true)

joern-lookup appears to function correctly (asking for options)

I correctly generate the .joernIndex file w/out issue and start the neo4j server (pointing at .joernIndex). My problem comes whenever I attempt to use a gremlin command. Following the VLC player example, I cant get past this point:

(issue in Docker image):

```
echo 'g.v(0).out()' | joern-lookup -g
 py2neo.error.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
```

Issue on manual installation:

```
echo 'g.v(0).out()' | joern-lookup -g
py2neo.error.BadInputException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method out() on null object
```

Full traces can be provided if needed.

I've also attempted other examples including the "main" function detection and the example provided in the Article without success.

Any advice to troubleshoot these issues or work-around them?

Answer (score 0):

As a possible workaround, Cisco Talos actually did some work with Joern recently, and they created a Docker image with the necessary setup for Joern.  You can find the image [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/neepl/joern/), or just grab the image via `docker pull neepl/joern`. The github for their work is [here](https://github.com/Cisco-Talos/covnavi), and the second part of the README details how to get Joern running using their container.  Hope this helps!